# Узнать количество элементов в таблице

Tags: php, doctrine, mysql

Добрый день.

Получилось так, что нужно узнать кол-во элементов в таблице, но выводить их с помощью `limit & offset`.

Пример выхлопа в json:

```
{ count: 106, data: 
    [ 
      { name: "Вася" }, 
      { name: "Пупкин"}
    ]
}
```

Пробовал по разному. Последний вариант таков:

```
$routesColl = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('r.*')
            ->from('Routes r')
            ->addSelect('count(r.id) as count')
            ->where('r.creator=?', SessionManager::getInstance()->getUid())
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy('count DESC')
            ->execute();
```

Но... выхлоп, к сожалению, не тот :-(